# With cordova facebook plugin: run/build android not work

Tags: facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to add the plugin: cordova-plugin-facebook4 in my application with the `ionic cordova plugin add command cordova-plugin-facebook4 - variable APP_ID =" 092809180912829 "--various APP_NAME =" test "
But whenever I install the plugin and use`ionic cordova build android`
I receive:

`[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.`

But if I remove the plugin, works perfectly build and run android.

I'm using ionic 4.3.0 / Cordova CLI 7.0.0 / Cordova platform: 7.0.0

Can anyone tell me what it can be? I found a lot on the internet, but none of the solutions worked for me and I no longer know what it can be. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can install the ionic-native facebook wrapper.

> npm install @ionic-native/facebook@beta

and follow the instructions on [Ionic-native facebook](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/)